# Access a class from a different target with marked as "public"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I created a new target and added a class with the access modifier "Public".
But i can't see this class.

[image: http://s23.postimg.org/ikqn0zlvu/Screen_Shot_2015_02_27_at_12_27_28.jpg]

From the docs i read "public entities are intended for use as API, and can be accessed by any file that imports the module, e.g. as a framework used in several of your projects."
So my guess is that im not importing the module/target?

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=5
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

public accessor control doesn't mean "public across target", it means public in "linked object files".

You need to select your `FooClass.swift` file and on the right in the `File inspector`, there is a `Target Membership`, you should check all the target that you want the file to be used.